# Why doesn't my favicon appear?

Tags: html, favicon

I want to add a favicon to my github.io page but it will not appear.  I amhosting my favicon on dropbox as a .png.  My code on my index.html page is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5dt587axxwvj2ft/arg_favicon.png?dl=0" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: Telling browsers that the PNG is type="image/x-icon" is a bad idea.

Comment: what should i change it to?

Comment: The correct mime type for PNG-images. "image/png", unsurprisingly.

Comment: ended up not needing it at all, surprise!

Comment: Not really a surprise. But telling browsers something that is outright wrong is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated based on asker's comment**

All you really need is:

```
<link rel="icon" href="//photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AADgf5ha0ZRZ9q_VZGT9I6cP9Sk27rCN26PvVDe82RKGgg/12/207862012/png/1024x768/3/1420758000/0/2/arg_favicon.png/CPzxjmMgAyACIAEoAigB/gPsvlZzDk2FAwU_MD5BJvE_4GAbCtJg6ORwdcMq1esQ">
```

**EDIT** I've created a page for you with your icon hosted on  github and here is the link and code:
http://grandstaffdesign.com/ITO/test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test page</title>
<link rel="icon" href="//photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AADgf5ha0ZRZ9q_VZGT9I6cP9Sk27rCN26PvVDe82RKGgg/12/207862012/png/1024x768/3/1420758000/0/2/arg_favicon.png/CPzxjmMgAyACIAEoAigB/gPsvlZzDk2FAwU_MD5BJvE_4GAbCtJg6ORwdcMq1esQ">
</head>
<body>
Answer for cbunn
</body>
</html>
```

**insight** 
I was able to get your link working by using the actual link of the image. The one you left in the comment was a php redirect that displays the image indirectly.

Comment: i don't have a server.  my website is a github page so it is hosted through them.  Can i host my favicon with github or somewhere else?

Comment: you can. I made an example page for you here: http://grandstaffdesign.com/ITO/test.html @cbunn i've also updated my answer with the code and link

Comment: whoops I had the wrong link in my code.  the right dropbox link is this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5dt587axxwvj2ft/arg_favicon.png?dl=0 .  The link in my question already works for me but for some reason this new link I am providing does not.

Comment: @cbunn Ok I have updated my answer and the link and it now works. http://grandstaffdesign.com/ITO/test.html please mark this as the answer if it helped you.

Comment: that did it.  I thought it had something to do with that link.  did you just right-click the image to get the correct link?

Comment: I inspected the element on google chrome, then clicked on the php link that you were using. It allowed me to view the resources of the page and I found the true url of the image. @cbunn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68444/discussion-between-cbunn-and-sanova).